# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow2.0

I trained a simple mnist model with **tensorflow 2.0** on **Google Colab** and saved it in the **.json** format. [Click here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15Pr20eximHhrkvsCGHPgwMUQKpPyShRd) to check out the Colab Notebook where I've written the code. Then on running the command

`!simple_tensorflow_serving --model_base_path="/" --model_platform="tensorflow"`

It is showing the error AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'

[simple_tensorflow_serving](https://github.com/tobegit3hub/simple_tensorflow_serving) helps in easily deploying trained tensorflow model into production.

**Versions** I'm using:

(1) TensorFlow - 2.0

(2) simple_tensorflow_serving - 0.6.4

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue with `FullTokenizer(vocab_file, do_lower_case)` in TF 2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simple Tensorflow Serving is not ready for Tensorflow 2.0, since it is using the old API.
In Tensorflow 2.0 the `gfile` package has been moved into `tf.io`.

Then, you have to downgrade your Tensorflow instance to TF 1.13 use Simple Tensorflow Serving

Comment: How do you downgrade it?

Comment: pip install tensorflow==1.13

Comment: Incase anyone gets here and is getting  "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.13".


Please use ---->      pip install tensorflow==1.13.1

Answer (score 46):

> In 2.0, tf.gfile.* is replaced by tf.io.gfile.*.

when I get error:

```
  File "/Users/MRJ/anaconda3/envs/python37-tf2.1/lib/python3.7/
site-packages/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py",
line 137, in load_labelmap

with tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'r') as fid:
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'
```

1.Find `label_map_util.py` line 137.

2.Replace `tf.gfile.GFile` to `tf.io.gfile.GFile`

It's worked for me.

[tensorflow issue #31315](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31315)

Comment: Did you have any errors for other commands in tensorflow? I want to know if changing this will cause any other issues

Comment: No.   
"In 2.0, tf.gfile.* is replaced by tf.io.gfile.*."  So tf.io.gfile.GFile  alway is right.

Answer (score 5):

Instead, try

```
tf.io.gfile.GFile(
    name, mode='r'
)
```

i.e ".io" will solve your all problems instead of downgrading your tf

Answer (score 0):

change `tf.gfile.GFile` to `tf.io.gfile.GFile`.

it works for this instance but not for all other files

example `tf.io.gfile.FastGFile` throws an error saying

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.io.gfile' has no attribute 'FastGFile'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is deprecated in TensorFlow 2.0.
You can use older tensorflow version to use this api like 1.13.1

In my older project I needed this api
Created a virtual environment in ananconda with this version like:

```
conda create -n tf python=3.7 tensorflow=1.13.1 
// here more modules with specific version can be added

conda activate tf // to activate environment tf

(base) D:\ff\testM>  --> (tf) D:\ff\testM> 
// After this environment changed to (base) --> (tf)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'` indicates that the TensorFlow module being used in your code does not have the gfile attribute. This could be due to a version mismatch or changes in the TensorFlow API.

In older versions of TensorFlow, gfile was part of the `tensorflow` module and could be accessed like `tensorflow.gfile`. However, in newer versions, it has been moved to `tf.compat.v1.gfile`.

To fix this change your import from `tensorflow.gfile` to `tf.compat.v1.gfile`

And there should be no need to downgrade your version of `tensorflow`.