# TensorFlow2.0.0 Alpha- module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got the above error when running the followed Python code on Windows10 with  Python 3.7.0 with tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
%matplotlib inline

from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\User\\models\\research\\object_detection\\data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')
PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\User\\models\\research\\object_detection\\ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17', 'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

PATH_TO_CKPT = PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH

with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    with tf.compat.v2.io.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

NUM_CLASSES=90
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
```

Any suggestions?
Kindly,
Gilad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591437/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-gfile)

Answer (score 1):

`gfile` is moved to `tf.io` in `tensorflow-2`.
so you need to import `tf.io` instead of just importing `tensorflow as tf`

Answer (score 0):

In tf2.0 , the gfile package has been moved into tf.io. so u can use tf.io.gfile