# Tensorflow tf.gfile.GFile

Tags: tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, machine-learning-model

I have tried changing `tf.gfile.GFile` to tf.io.gfile.GFile and also tried `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf` but nothing worked. It is not reading the newly saved file. I have saved it after changes.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-efc7822bb0d7> in <module>
----> 1 config = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(CONFIG_PATH)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/utils/config_util.py in get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config_path, config_override)
     94   """
     95   pipeline_config = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()
---> 96   with tf.gfile.GFile(pipeline_config_path, "r") as f:
     97     proto_str = f.read()
     98     text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile''''
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591437/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-gfile)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to tf.io.gfile.GFile.